# Using angular to display different timestamps depending on age of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is similar to the messages app on an iphone, where newer text messages you get will simply show you the time in a format like `9:55 PM`, but once they are a day old it says `Yesterday`, and anything older than a day says the day of that week `Monday`, `Tuesday`, etc, anything older than that week just displays that date like `12/22/2014`.

I've been able to successfully format my timestamps using the date filter:

```
{{message.timestamp | date:"h:mm a" }}
```

What would work best for something like this, a custom filter? Is it possible purely in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) date library with angular filter to achieve that. moment has various standard formatting expressions available. Take a look at the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Include moment.js in your application, you can download it or refer to a cdn location. Example:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js
```

Create a filter:

```
.constant('moment', window.moment) //Save moment in constant for ease of dependency injection
.filter('dateMoment', ['moment', function(moment){
  return function(input){
    //Return formatted date
    if(!input) return '_';
    return moment(input).calendar();
  }
}]);
```

Use the filter with the binding:

```
{{message.timestamp | dateMoment }}
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
  var currDt = new Date();
  $scope.messages = [{
    message: 'message1',
    date: currDt
  }, {
    message: 'message11',
    date: (new Date(currDt)).setDate(currDt.getDate()-1)
  }, {
    message: 'message3',
    date: (new Date(currDt)).setDate(currDt.getDate()-3)
  }, {
    message: 'message4',
    date: (new Date(currDt)).setDate(currDt.getDate()-4)
  }, {
    message: 'message5',
    date: (new Date(currDt)).setDate(currDt.getDate()-5)
  }, {
    message: 'message2',
    date: (new Date(currDt)).setDate(currDt.getDate()-30)
  }]
}).constant('moment', moment).filter('dateMoment', ['moment',
  function(moment) {
    return function(input) {
      return moment(input).calendar();
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="moment.js@*" data-semver="2.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg.message}} ---- {{msg.date|dateMoment}}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @knishka Yup moment is a pretty standard date library... :)